# display images in local machines from a web server

Tags: asp.net

My question is about accessing local machines' files from a webserver..

I have an intranet project that works on my network..

My project is about accessing the other local machines,then displaying images from that machines..

For example my project is working on 192.168.9.170...when enter the site..it can be displayed lots of images from local machines..for example an image of them  src path is:192.168.9.180, one of them is 192.168.9.181..

So,i want to publish this project on web.Can i access local machines from webserver..how can i map that machines

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Hi 
If you can access these peoples machines from the web server using a unc path e.g. //servername/volume/folder/file then you may be able to copy the files from the machines on the network to your web server and view.  You would need permissions to do this, so not sure how viable that is.

Alternativly you could use Silverlight to access the files locally
http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/12/16/silverlight-4-s-new-local-file-system-support.aspx

Cheers Tigger

Comment: i think,i have to copy files to my server.then set the path from server it will be displayed.

Comment: Actually i have to access audio files as well as images..it doesnt matter to copy image files but copying audio files time makes me angry..i do not know how it can be faster..maybe i need more help for this issue